# CSS3 - grid-template-areas not spanning correctly

Tags: css, grid, css-grid

When I try to utilize grid-areas, they are not spanning the appropriate amount of columns. The grid-template-columns property is however working fine and it displays as if I was not using the grid-areas at all.

scss:

```
.mygrid {
  display: grid;
  padding: 3%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "a7" "a5" "a10" "a15" "a20";
  grid-gap: 0.4em;
  @media (min-width: 400px) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "a7 a7"
      "a5 a10"
      "a15 a20";
  }
  @media (min-width: 600px) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
      "a7 a7 a7 a7"
      "a5 a10 a15 a20";
  }
  .box {
    display: inline;
    padding: 1em;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .a7 {
    grid-area: a7;
  }
  .a5 {
    grid-area: a5;
  }
  .a10 {
    grid-area: a10;
  }
  .a15 {
    grid-area: a15;
  }
  .a20 {
    grid-area: a20;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="mygrid">
    <div id="7" class="box a7">
      <span>7</span>
    </div>

    <div id="5" class="box a5">
      <span>5</span>
    </div>

    <div id="10" class="box a10">
     <span>10</span>
    </div>

    <div id="15" class="box a15">
      <span>15</span>
    </div>

    <div id="20" class="box a20">
      <span>20</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm unsure what is causing this issue, my code appears correct

despite attempting @vals answer in my project, I am still receiving the same issue. Is there something well known that could cascade down and cause this to break?

I have also validated my html to make sure there were no errors causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change identifiers to non-numbers:

```css
.mygrid {
  display: grid;
  padding: 3%;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "a7" "a5" "a10" "a15" "a20";
  grid-gap: 0.4em;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .mygrid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "a7 a7" "a5 a10" "a15 a20";
  }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .mygrid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "a7 a7 a7 a7" "a5 a10 a15 a20";
  }
}

.box {
  display: inline;
  padding: 1em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.b7 {
  grid-area: a7;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.b5 {
  grid-area: a5;
}

.b10 {
  grid-area: a10;
}

.b15 {
  grid-area: a15;
}

.b20 {
  grid-area: a20;
}
```

```html
<div class="mygrid">
  <div id="7" class="box b7">
    <span>7</span>
  </div>

  <div id="5" class="box b5">
    <span>5</span>
  </div>

  <div id="10" class="box b10">
    <span>10</span>
  </div>

  <div id="15" class="box b15">
    <span>15</span>
  </div>

  <div id="20" class="box b20">
    <span>20</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had attempted that, and just tried again but it is still give me the same issue.

Comment: I didn't even notice the snippet. So then it must be something outside this code affecting it... I had attempted adding `clear: both`, to the `mygrid` div but that didn't solve it. Would anyone have an idea of what could cascade to cause this to break?

Comment: Have you noticed that I changed both the class names and the area names ?

Comment: My compiler must have been stopped during my edits, its working now with all these changes. Thanks so much.

Comment: Happy that it helped you !